# Update jsonb array value stored as text in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.5

Postgres Version: 9.5.0

I have a database table where one of the columns is stored as text that represents a json value. The json value is an array of dictionaries e.x.:

```
[{"picture": "XXX", "image_hash": null, "name": "test",  "video": null, "link": "http://www.google.com", "table_id": 356}, ..]
```

I am trying to update the value associated to the key `table_id` **only for the 1st array element**. Here is the query I ran:

```
update table1 set "json_column" = jsonb_set("json_column", "{0, table_id}", null, false) where id = 1;
```

I keep running into the error - `ERROR:  column "{0, table_id}" does not exist`

Could someone please help me out understanding how this can be fixed?

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should really [update to the latest 9.5 release](https://why-upgrade.depesz.com/show?from=9.5&to=9.5.16)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: It's not upto me to do that.